# Vector component plot as histogram

Tags: plotting, graphics

I am diagonalizing a real matrix as a function of a internal parameter. I can plot the spectrum of the system as a function of this internal parameters. How can I  plot now the eigenstates components as an histogram as in this figure?

Here some additional information:

The matrix that I am diagonalizing is a dimerized chain given by the following code:

```
With[{patternT = {v, w}, 
   patternE = {0, 0}}, 
  SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}, {2 m, 2 m}] -> patternE, 
    Band[{1, 2}, {-2, -1}] -> patternT, 
    Band[{2, 1}, {-1, -2}] -> patternT, {1, 2 m} -> BC w, {2 m, 1} -> BC w}, {2 m, 2 m}]];
```

From the eigenvalues I can make a plot as a function of the parameter `w` for fixed `v`. Now I would like to plot the components of Eigenvector of this matrix.

I know that the components correspond in block of two to the index `m`. How can I make an histogram of these components so to respect the index `m`?

I tried with `Histogram[vec]` but the output is different from what I am looking for that should be similar to the figure below. I can reproduce the spectrum [panel (a)] diagonalizing the matrix above, by an opportune rearrangement the results and than using `PlotLineList[]`.

How can I reproduce panels (b) to (d) if I have the eigenstates?

[image]

The figure is in the book "**A Short Course on Topological Insulators**" by *János K. Asbóth, László Oroszlány, András Pályi*, Lecture Notes in Physics
 **919** (Springer, 2016) and is about the spectrum and the eigenstates of the [SSH](http://theorie.physik.uni-konstanz.de/burkard/sites/default/files/ts15/TalkSSH.pdf) for conducting polymers.

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect not formulating any question?

Comment: How can I plot the components of the eigenstates as an histogram?

Comment: [`Histogram[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html)?

Comment: Do you want a `Histogram` or just a `BarChart`?

Comment: Thanks JasonB, I guess that `BarChart` should work, I have to understand how it works.

Comment: Solved by using `BarChart` and `ChartStyle` for the alternating colors. Sorry again for placing the question the first time in an unclear way.

Comment: Glad I could help clear that up.  Don't hesitate to come back if you have more issues.  Also if you want to reopen the question to post your answer the mods might go for that.